# Transferring Variable Range of Data to New Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry if this is a simple fix, I'm a novice with VBA.  Basically I have a bunch of sheets in a workbook (input, called it Test) and want to transfer all the data to a new workbook (output, called it Batch1).  The top two rows in the input need to be combined into the top row in the output, I've already done this successfully.

The rest of the data (row 3 and down for all the columns in all the sheets in the input) needs to be placed in row 2 and down in the proper columns in the output.  I would like to avoid using the clipboard as I have read that it complicates things.  I believe my issue is that the way I am looping through the columns in the worksheets means that the range of data is variable, I have tried to remedy this.  Here is my code.

```
Sub Headings()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer 'define variables
     Dim j As Integer
     Dim k As Integer
     k = 1
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim out As Workbook
     Dim Data As Range
     Dim Space As Range
     Dim InC1 As Range
     Dim InC2 As Range
     Dim OutC1 As Range
     Dim OutC2 As Range
     Set out = Workbooks("Batch1.xlsm")

     ' Set up worksheet loop.
     For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        colCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns.Count 'Count number of coloumns in particular worksheet
        RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count  'Count number of rows in particular worksheet

        'Looped Code Follows

        For j = 1 To colCount

        ws.Activate 'Activate input worksheet in question

        Parameter = Cells(1, j)
        Units = Cells(2, j)

        Combine = Parameter & "  " & Units 'Combine top two rows with space between

        Set InC1 = Cells(3, j)
        Set InC2 = Cells(RowCount, j)
        Set Data = Range("InC1:InC2")

        out.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate 'Open output worksheet

        Cells(1, k) = Combine 'Input values into output sheet

        Set OutC1 = Cells(2, k)
        Set OutC2 = Cells(RowCount, k)
        Set Space = Range("OutC1:OutC2")
        Space = Data

        k = k + 1 'Steps through columns, keeping space in output

        Next j


     Next

  End Sub
```

I have been getting a variety of errors, I think it's to do with how I'm defining the range of data for each column "j".  Also for some reason the row count is returning a value of 47 despite the fact that there are only 17-20 rows in each sheet of the input, this won't change anything but is annoying.

Please don't feel like you need to fix my code, just writing a simple function to show me where I messed up is more than enough.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code.  See the notes:

```
Sub Headings()

 Dim WS_Count As Integer 'define variables
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim k As Integer
 k = 1
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim out As Workbook
 Dim Data As Range
 Dim Space As Range
 Dim InC1 As Range
 Dim InC2 As Range
 Dim OutC1 As Range
 Dim OutC2 As Range
 Dim ows As Worksheet
 Dim rowCount&
 Set out = Workbooks("Batch1.xlsm")
 Set ows = out.Sheets("Sheet1")
 ' Set up worksheet loop.
 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    colCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns.Count 'Count number of coloumns in particular worksheet
    rowCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count  'Count number of rows in particular worksheet

    'Looped Code Follows

    For j = 1 To colCount
        'avoid activate by setting the parentage directly.
        'ws.Activate 'Activate input worksheet in question

        Parameter = ws.Cells(1, j)
        Units = ws.Cells(2, j)

        Combine = Parameter & "  " & Units 'Combine top two rows with space between

        Set InC1 = ws.Cells(3, j)
        Set InC2 = ws.Cells(rowCount, j) 
        Set Data = ws.Range(InC1.Address(0,0) & ":" & InC2.Address(0,0)) 'variable need to outsid the qoutes

        'out.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate 'Open output worksheet

        ows.Cells(1, k) = Combine 'Input values into output sheet

        Set OutC1 = ows.Cells(2, k)
        Set OutC2 = ows.Cells(rowCount, k)
        Set Space = ows.Range(OutC1.Address(0,0) & ":" & OutC2.Address(0,0))
        Space.Value = Data.Value

        k = k + 1 'Steps through columns, keeping space in output

    Next j


 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay, I was on vacation.  It seems to work until the Space.Value=Data.Value line which returns the runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: An update: it gives me that error but seems to work.  Is there anyway to avoid this?  I am writing these macros remotely for an internship I am starting in late June.  I worry it will seem unprofessional if an error message comes up even if the macros themselves work.

Comment: I mentioned them two comments up I believe.

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of Data.Value when it breaks?

Comment: How do i check that? From the 'locals' window?  If so it is collapsible with many subs underneath and has value of:

+ : Data :  : Range/Range
  - : Value2 :  : Variant/Variant(1 to 29, 1 to 1)

Comment: Sorry I forgot it was more than one cell. Are there any errors in the range?    Errors in the cells will cause it to stop.

Comment: Do I check from the locals window again?

If so I don't think so as:     : Errors : <Application-defined or object-defined error> : Errors


The code actual works fine so If it's just something weird going on it's not a huge deal.

Comment: Check the actual data.  You should be able to find the actual range where it stops and then go to that sheet and look at the data.  If it works for most of the data then the problem is not with the script but with the data.  So fix the data or put checks in the code to deal with the problems in the data.  I cannot test from here, my crystal ball is in the shop at the moment.  Look at the data and see what is different with it from those that are working, then look and make sure that the variable that set the ranges are good.  As in look at InC1,InC2... and make sure they are not errors.

Answer (score 1):

If, as appears, you just want to copy a range from one worksheet to another (even if that other sheet is in a different workbook) you can just set one range's `Value` to the others:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rng1 = Sheets(1).UsedRange
Set rng2 = Sheets(2).Range("A1").Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count)

rng2.Value = rng1.Value
```

This doesn't use the clipboard.

`Resize` is used to make sure the two areas are of the same size.

You need to modify this to include the reference to the second Workbook (and use the `Worksheets` collection rather than `Sheets`).

You can adjust the ranges to suit your requirements (or copy the entire range then replace the first row(s)).

---

To address a couple of issues with the OP's code:

This

```
    Set Data = Range("InC1:InC2")
```

is using the literal text "InC1:InC2" it is not substituting these variables' values. It should be

```
    Set Data = ws.Range(InC1.Address(0,0) & ":" & InC2.Address(0,0))
```

or

```
    Set Data = ws.Range(InC1.Cells(1), InC2.Cells(1))
    'not worrying about dollar signs
```

You also should avoid Activate (and Select) routinely, they are inefficient and unnecessary. Setting explicit references to Workbooks and Worksheets helps to avoid their use, but also makes the code less error-prone - it is quite easy otherwise to think you are referring to a range in one sheet when you are still referring to a range in another sheet.

Comment: The OP is not using the clipboard in the code above.  `Space = Data`  There is not copy paste anywhere

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that the OP was using the clipboard, just emphasizing that my code example doesn't use it either.

Comment: I 100% agree that assigning the values directly instead of copy and paste special is the way to go, the problem is that this does not address the problem with this particular code as the OP is already using this method.  So as a great method this is correct, as an answer to why the code above is not working it is not.  At first I thought you were answering a different question altogether.  Just an opinion.

Comment: Fair enough. Given that the OP said "Please don't feel like you need to fix my code, just writing a simple function to show me where I messed up is more than enough." I am happy posting my sample code as an example and answer.

Comment: I can see that, and applaud the idea greatly.  Maybe show the other two errors; the using of variables inside text strings and the assigning the proper parent sheets to the various ranges.  These are the two major problems with the code.

Comment: @Scott Craner OP code with some modifications for proper syntax done by you only combines row 1 and row 2 and writes in sheet 1 Header Line. He has to address the issues raised by you in your comments. No other data is getting written to sheet1. Sample data file has been uploaded to <https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdykbw88sr91qyn/transferring%20data.xlsm?dl=0>

Comment: @skkakkar no offense but I do not download .xlsm files from the internet.  Not that I think you are trying anything wrong, It is just a personal policy.  And as I do not have access to any data I would be guessing.  This does put other data in beside the headers, `Space = Data` should do that.

Comment: @Scott Craner Should I upload a copy of xlsx file , basically i have tested on your code as it is corrected one. If you like you can have a run on the sample data. I will also paste code followed on a blank worksheet. Sorry I am getting a doubt and rechecking my processing. I shall revert back to you.

Comment: @skkakkar this should be a conversation under my post.  Feel free to fix my problems and post your own answer.  I would welcome the insight.

Comment: @ScottCraner As per your suggestion I've added a couple of points to my answer ;). `Space = Data` is assigning one range reference to another, `.Value` needs to be used to copy the data across.

Comment: Yow are correct I missed that I will fix it in my code thanks for the catch and ++ for the edit.